# Getting HDTracks music download application working under wine in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, wine, 64-bit, music

Does anyone here buy music from HDTracks, using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

In 13.10 32 bit I used to be able to buy music using their Windows application under Wine, but now when I try, I cannot log in through the application to their site - the application tells me that "there was a problem logging in" and to try again later.

I have tried running in a 32bit WINEARCH to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get the application working on a 32 bit Ubuntu but not on 64 bit.

Because I'm not really interested in having a bunch of Winjunk on my system, I make the purchase on Linux and then find a Windows PC I can use to do the download.

It appears that HDTracks is not the only organization to use this download application, made by JRiver.  I question the worth of it but anyway...

Comment: I just thought why not use ReactOS? Well… it's not a 64-Bit OS, so there won't be any up to date web browsers. After finally managing to get it to run and install the latest Firefox 32-Bit version the HDTracks installer aborted with *R6025 - pure virtual function call*. I guess I have to use my Windows Insider VM instead.

Answer (score 0):

JRiver provides a Linux version (a .deb file).  Last time I used it, I could download my music without problems, but the program crashes on exit.  Oh well, I guess that's better than crashing on startup!!!!

Here is the article on their forums:

https://yabb.jriver.com/interact/index.php?topic=92748.0